# When backing up a postgres database I get prompted for a password

Tags: database, bash, postgresql, ubuntu

I'm busy backing up my postgres db, I run the following command

```
pg_dump -d data -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1 -CdiOv > data.sql
```

I however have one problem I get asked for the password, if I want to add this into a cron I do not want to get promted for the password. Is there any way to do this without the password prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: **never** use -d option to pg_dump. Do you even know what it does?

Second: use [pgpass](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/libpq-pgpass.html) file or [PGPASSWORD](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/libpq-envars.html) env variable.

Comment: I'll bite. I do know what -d is for and have needed it sometimes (cross database engine migrations on occasion). Do you mean "it doesn't do what you think it does" or do you really man "never"?

Comment: @newt - not sure where you're migrating to, but migration is the case when you can use inserts. for backups there is no point.

Comment: @Roland: it's slow. and most people use it because they think it's "--database". And it is dropped in 8.4 (finally).

Comment: @depesz - ok, makes sense. I was migrating to mysql (I know, that's just plain *wrong*) and it was the quickest way at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Use ~/.pgpass.
[pgpass documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html)

Lots more details to be found on Google, searching for "pg_dump password".